# Assigning several model instances of one Model to another Model, and then comparing them?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model called Hero, which has a lot of different objects.

I'm having the user select 4 instances of Hero in a form, and assigning them to a Match model to register what Heroes they played with.

I've tried creating a Deck model, that could contain the 4 heroes and then assign that Deck model in Match model and form, but then the user can't select a new combination, only current Deck combinations.
This works fine in the adminpanel, where I can add new combinations, but the user doesn't get that opportunity.
It's not quite what I want and I can't wrap my head around, is how I can then later compare two instances of Deck or the selected Heroes in Match to see if the user selected the same Heroes in their Deck/Match and/or count how many times that specific combination of Hero is used in a deck/Match.

In short: What I want is for the user to, through a form, select 4 Hero objects and save them to a Deck model. If their specific combination of selected Heroes is already in Deck, then it should register it under that.

I know it's confusing, but that's owing to I'm pretty new with Django and hence, probably not going about this the right way.

I have not included views.py or templates, since they're working fine. But if someone needs them I can put them up. Also the models are quite more extensive, but I've included shortened versions of them to illustrate.

```
**models.py**
class Hero(models.Model):
    heroname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True)

class Deck(models.Model):
    heroes = models.ManyToManyField(Hero)

**forms.py**
class DeckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    deck = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
      queryset=Hero.objects.all(),
      widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
      required=False
      )

  def clean(self):
      cleaned_data = super().clean()
      if cleaned_data.get('deck').count() != 4:
          raise ValidationError('You must select 4 heroes for a deck.')

  class Meta:
      model = Deck
      fields = ['deck']
```

Comment: So if I understand well, If the combination of heroes already exists in the deck, you want to re-use that deck instance instead of creating a new one, correct? Also, In your form, you give the possibility to select the same hero multiple times, which i guess is something you don't want?

Comment: Just a suggestion, i would recommend you to rename the field `deck` in the `Deck` model, to `heroes`, since it refers to multiple heroes and you would be able to do `deck.heroes.all()` instead of `deck.deck.all()`.

Comment: @Agey Yes, that is exactly what I want. And I will rename my field according to your suggestion, that is indeed better. Thanks.

Comment: Also, yes, they can select the same hero several times, which should not be possible, but I have another working form setup that uses CheckboxSelectMultiple and a clean method that validates 4 selected. But thanks for noticing.

Comment: I have read your post a few times, but I do not really know how to help. It seems you have more of an architecture problem rather than a programming issue. Find me in IRC in freenode `irc.freenode.net`. You can find me in the django channel. Ill try to help you further there. You know how to use IRC?